# Windows 10 21H1 two distinct issues: Most likely related to TPM/Secure Boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, troubleshooting

Update: New question with more current information over here: [Windows 10 Bootup Slowness Issue Part 2](https://superuser.com/questions/1664350/windows-10-bootup-slowness-issue-part-2)

This will be a bit longwinded so bear with me.

A few days ago, I got the notification that Windows 10 21H1 was ready to be patch on my main desktop that I use for pretty much everything.

At first I noticed a bit of slowdown between pressing power on and getting to the Windows 10 account login screen. At first, it wasn't too bad and I kind of put off trying to fix it for a bit. Real life got in the way and all that.

A few days ago, I decided to roll up my sleeve to fix the slowdown as it was becoming more and more pronounced. Pre-21H1 my PC used to take a few second to boot up. Post-21H1 it start to take at least 15 to 30 minutes (Yes you read it right and no it is not a mistypo) between power button and Windows Account Login screen.

So I started with those steps: sfc /scannow, DISM /RestoreHealth, and lastly creating a media image to re-install Windows 10 21H1 in-place. None of those worked.

---

I start looking into turning on feature within BIOS/UEFI, primarily UEFI mode and secure boot and fTPM, in preparation for Windows 11 at the same time.

---

By luck, I manage to convert Windows 10 from legacy (I don't know why it was like that in the first place...) to UEFI mode and through stroke of luck manage to get the time between power button and Windows 10 account login down closer to what it used to be from before 21H1 update. I confirmed that the Windows 10 was indeed working in UEFI mode through MSinfo32 once.

While there I also noticed that Windows TPM was whining about PCR7 binding and from what little I saw reading up on it. I noticed that you need secure boot to be on and I remembered that it wasn't on. Seems like a simple fix to reboot into BIOS and enable it right?

---

This is when my Windows 10 completely bricks itself. I tried creating a new different Windows 10 USB media image. It will not recognize that I have a Windows 10 OS anywhere on my hardware that I was able to boot once in UEFI mode. Opening up command prompt is the only thing I can do and it will not let me change domain to C:\ which is where my OS is at. All other option via troubleshooting do not work or ask me to "restart" and log on Windows 10... Useless media image installer being a tool.

---

Both issue persist which means to tweak and work through every possible combination of TPM/Secure Boot would take at least 2 hours and I have bang my head on this for the entire afternoon yesterday and all morning today.

If it helps my motherboard is X370 Fatal1ty pro gaming and CPU is Ryzen 3700X.

I would appreciate any help the community can offer at this point!

Edit: I manage to verify that hard drives are still intact via recovery environment.

[image: Hard drive description/Logical names]

Comment: 1) Do you have a backup that you can restore your data from? 2) Did you enable any features that use TPM, such as Bitlocker? 3) The drive letter with the OS on it may not be C: in a recovery environment.

Comment: The simplest solution is you should immediately disable Secure Boot.  You likely have to research how to load the required keys required for Secure Boot.  Since you were NOT using TPM to store your BitLocker key you should be fine disabling that.  Secure Boot is not required for Windows 10.  I realize you want it to work, but for the time being, that isn't your actual question.  Understanding exactly what messages you were displayed would help explain, how precisely, you can go about enabling it.  "will not let me change domain to C:\" if that's within WinRE it actually isn't.

Comment: I don't really have any backup for the OS.

I didn't use bitlocker or any feature that uses TPM as far I am aware of.

The USB bootup media letter started with X and I know that I don't have a drive that starts with X. I have several hard drives. They are all recognized by the model numbers in UEFI (examples: Samsung SSD ####,  #### PNY etc...). @AndrewMorton

Comment: I already disabled secure boot. Same error. Tried turning TPM to use local chip and secure boot still off. Then again with TPM turned off and secure boot off. Again, with Secure boot only on. Etc... I tried all possible combination.

It all results in a black screen asking me to insert a new bootable media. Yes the CD C:\ was inside of a recovery environment. @Ramhound

Comment: Your system should be on X: within WinRE.  However, it sounds whatever changes you made, hosed your installation.  What most likely happened is you have an invalid BCD and/or EFI entry in your NVRAM.  What should have happened, is once you enabled UEFI mode, and went to enable secure boot you should have selected the proper PKI for Windows.  I am guessing the option to select the proper PKI wasn't given to you?

Comment: The reason the system complained about Secure Boot is due to the fact, in order to enabled BitLocker to use the TPM, you must enable Secure Boot.  This doesn't mean BitLocker was attempting to be used and/or was enabled.  Listing your partitions within WinRE using DISKPART might help you understand what disks are detectable within WinRE

Comment: I went into the BIOS setting and enabled secure boot mode. I saw some option for installing "default keys". I think that is what you meant by PKI right?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ufi-mb6hgontJrwy3xeNl_TGBETB1JII/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ui2P6MhIOdMEARSoHeLww7EGtVlSFcXg/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ujKr1XHTJ7lWGPtqCwjHBwhV9qRsQQba/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1un_ju8y29yvKdOU8ZamwaINnTXcj-Djf/view?usp=sharing

I will look into diskpart and I may not be able to get back for a bit.

Comment: Your stuff on Google Drive is inaccessible to me.  If it's images [edit] your question otherwise I won't be able to see it.  You installed/enabled the keys but have you, configured Secure Boot, that you will be booting into Windows and not some other supported environment?  Yes, [PKI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-secure-boot-key-creation-and-management-guidance)

Comment: Sorry about that. It was a setting issue within google drive that I sometime forget about it. The images should be viewable and I tested it myself.

Comment: Good news. I just used "wmic logicaldisk get deviceid, volumename, description".

All of them show up including the drive where the OS is stored on which is obviously C:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v4tBQYYiShaVttCgfDyeZnTW-BP-dAHP/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-install Windows OS in-place multiple time but still doesn't resolve the boot up time.

My new updated question with more current information that I am aware of is here.

[Windows 10 Bootup Slowness Issue Part 2](https://superuser.com/questions/1664350/windows-10-bootup-slowness-issue-part-2)